# Constant time lookup for unions and finds

Tags: algorithm, big-o, graph-theory, union-find

I have a homework question that asks us to show that, for size-based union-find with path compression: if all unions are done before all finds, it takes O(n) time to do O(n) unions and O(n) finds.

My thought is that if there is a way to create a lookup table to track all of the node's roots as the unions are performed, then every single union or find will take place in constant time, making the process linear. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to make the lookup table adjustments in constant time. Any thoughts?

Comment: You say you are being asked to prove a property of the standard union-by-size-with-path-compression disjoint set data structure, but then you say that your idea is to create a new disjoint set data structure.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's correct. I feel that without creating a new data structure to specifically track the roots, then it is not possible to perform O(n) unions in O(n) time.

Comment: Indeed you cannot, because a union starts with 2 finds... but then are you really doing all the unions first?  I suggest you check the wording of the question carefully.  To solve the problem with a different data structure, you just build a graph during the union phase and find the connected components before the find phase.

Comment: @MattTimmermans This was later clarified for me by the professor. In this case, we are allowed to assume that we are guaranteed to only be conducting unions on a root. Obviously this makes the problem much easier, but it was not listed in the original assignment docs.